# Не отправляется письмо на почту

Tags: php, html

```
<form method='post'>
    <input type="text" name='mail' placeholder='Электронная почта'>
    <input type="submit">
</form>



<?php 
$random = rand(100000,999999);
$to = 'xxxx@icloud.com';
$subject = $random;
$text ='Мы отправили вам код для подтверждения вашей электронной почты';
$headers = "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8";
$headers.="From:webprojec@mail.ru";
$headers.="Reply-to:webprojec@mail.ru";
mail($to,$subject,$text,$headers);







?>
```

Comment: `From:webprojec@mail.ru` — и не будет отправляться, пока вы пытаетесь всех обмануть и выдать себя за mail.ru

Comment: @andreymal Будет. В поле `From` я могу написать что угодно. `RFC` этого не запрещает. Чем и пользуются спамеры.

Comment: @Леонид Каневский Смотрите ошибку которую Вам возвращает `error_get_last()`

Comment: @user413219 нет, не будет. Mail.ru [прописал для своего домена DMARC-правила](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=txt%3a_dmarc.mail.ru&run=toolpage) (RFC 7489), согласно которым письма, не прошедшие проверку подлинности (DKIM - RFC 6376, SPF - RFC 7208), должны отклоняться (даже не отправляться в папку «спам», а полностью отклоняться). И сервер получателя icloud.com вполне может ориентироваться на это правило и отклонять письмо.

Comment: @andreymal не путайте отправку через сам `mail.ru` с отправкой от имени `mail.ru`. Я через свой почтовый сервер могу отправить письма с указанием в поле `FROM` хоть Путина :)

Comment: @user413219 можете, потому что домен kremlin.ru не имеет SPF и DMARC-записей. А вот от имени mail.ru - не можете. От имени Билла Гейтса тоже не можете. Это вы не путайте, DKIM/SPF/DMARC записи из домена отправителя обрабатываются именно сервером получателя (если сервер такое поддерживает).

Comment: @andreymal даже при таком раскладе все что мне нужно - угадать ящик отправителя на `mail.ru`, если он существует `DKIM/SPF/DMARC ` не помогут

Comment: @user413219 помогут. Получатель проверит, что сервер отправителя не является подлинным (достаточно банальной проверки IP-адреса по SPF), и отклонит письмо - независимо от того, угадали вы ящик или нет. Вместо пустой болтовни уже могли бы проверить это в эксперименте :)

Comment: @andreymal никакой пустой болтовни. Все уже проверено. Если у меня на сервере не стоит тот же `DKIM/SPF` то мой сервер и не будет их проверять, а соотвественно и валидировать домен отправителя. Поэтому я и пишу, что на самом деле слишком много `если` в Вашем утверждении о невозможности отправить поддельное письмо от имени кого угодно.

Comment: @user413219 почти у любого крупного сервера такая проверка стоит - уверен, у icloud.com тоже.